# fread changes values of arguments?

Tags: c

```
FILE *inp = fopen(...);
int j, buff;
j = 40 - sizeof(int) - 4;
printf("%d\n", j);
fread(&buff, j, 1, inp);
printf("%d", j);
```

For some reason j is 32, then it jumps to some crazy high number in the second print. I'm fairly new to C but not to programming and can't figure this one out.

Comment: Please add the declaration of `buff`. Also, can you copy and paste your code instead of typing it in? The missing right paren in the first printf call makes me think you typed this by hand.

Comment: Well, for one thing you forgot to close the first printf call with a closing parenthesis

Comment: I have no idea what you wanted to achieve with `j = 40 - sizeof(int) - 4;`  What is `40`?  You need to explain it so that others can give you effective advices.

Comment: By the way, even after you fix the size of `buff` problem, you need to change your call to `fread(buff, sizeof(int), j, inp);`. Read the [fread documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since almost assuredly `buff` is a local array, it is stack allocated and fread is overwriting your stack including j since most likely `40 - sizeof(int) - 4` is greater than `sizeof(buff)`.

Yeah - there's your problem. `sizeof(buff) = sizeof(int)`, so assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4, you're asking to read 40 bytes, which will overwrite 36 bytes past buff.

If you're trying to read an array of ints, you should declare an array of ints (and read no more than its size).

If you're trying to read 40 ints, you should do something like this:

```
int buff[40];
size_t amountRead = fread(buff, sizeof(int), 40);
```

or if it makes you happy.

```
int buff[40];
size_t size = sizeof(buff);
size_t amountRead = fread(buff, size, 1);
```

The latter is better in that the code will work independent of changes to the the dimension of buff.

And just to stave off future questions, it looks like you can read and write structs using `fread`, and you can, but this is not a portable serialization strategy (mostly due to byte ordering, data type sizes and struct padding differences on differenct computers or compiler configurations).

It also looks like you can serialize arrays of integers with `fread`, and you can, but it is also not portable because of data type size differences and byte ordering differences.

As long as you're on one computer, one compiler, one set of compiler settings, you're OK.

Comment: Oh okay, so change the declaration to `int buff[40]`?

Comment: Figure out what the size should be, and change it accordingly. Do you want 40 ints? Your code isn't reading 40 ints.

Comment: I'll be changing computers but will always use `gcc`

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of fread is

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

Where

`size` This is the size in bytes of each element to be read.

In your case you are trying to read 32 bytes into 4 byte int which is undefined behavior.

If you have `int buff[40];`

The buff can hold 40 integer elements so the call can be like

```
fread(buff,sizeof(buff),1,inp);
```

Comment: So change the declaration to `int buff[40]`?

Comment: Yes the point is you should have enough memory to read the number of bytes asked you . Yes an array should be fine but make sure there is no array out of bound access